# SVG text element with Unicode characters

Tags: javascript, unicode, svg

First - a short description of a problem. I write a JavaScript function to put some text label's in SVG canvas. Here it is:

```js
function set_label(x,y,title)
{
 var newTitle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
 newTitle.setAttributeNS(null,"x",x);
 newTitle.setAttributeNS(null,"y",y);
 newTitle.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","17px");
 newTitle.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","WinGreek");      
 var textNode = document.createTextNode(title);
 newTitle.appendChild(textNode);
 document.getElementById("viewport").appendChild(newTitle);   
}
```

I must use Greek font due to my project points. So, I call function:

```js
set_label (10,50,'Qitos')
```

this will display Ktitos label - no problem.

But - when i try to call like this:

```js
set_label (10,50,'Qam&#218;raj')
```

or even worse:

```js
set_label (10,50,'&#920;&#945;&#961;&#963;&#945;&#957;&#948;&#945;&#955;&#945;')
```

this must display Θαρσανδαλα title formed all from special characters - a problem accrue - utf-8 symbol appear like i write it - with code :(

After some research here in other similar question's, i find that if I convert UTF-8 code to ESC sequence, like \U00B0 - this must solve that problem, but...
- I cant figure it how to do this and
- how to do that if special character is in middle of string - like second example

Comment: I relabelled this as unicode instead of UTF-8 since it has nothing to do with UTF-8.  There is no such thing as a UTF-8 symbol.  Unicode defines a mapping between integers and symbols.  UTF-8 defines a mapping between integers and byte sequences.  See http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-unicode-and-utf-8/ for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Thsnk's Mike Samuel :) You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's really easy: just put the actual Unicode characters you want into your document, save the document as UTF-8, and specify that the document is using the UTF-8 character set.

Here's [a live example on my website](http://phrogz.net/SVG/unicode.svg) showing that you can use these characters:

- In the title of the page.
- Directly in your text.
- Inside JavaScript strings.

Note that I've saved this file with a UTF-8 encoding and notice that the top of the file has:

```xml
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
```

On the off chance that my site is down, here's the content of the example:

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type"
        content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Θαρσανδαλα</title> 
  <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    body { background:#eee; margin:0 }
    svg { display:block; border:1px solid #ccc; margin:2em auto;
          width:300px; height:200px; background:#fff }
    svg text { text-anchor:middle }
  </style> 
</head><body>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
       viewBox="-150 -100 300 200">
    <text>Inline: Θαρσανδαλα</text>
  </svg> 
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var svg  = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];     
    createOn(svg,'text',{y:20,"font-size":"17px"},"Generated: Θαρσανδαλα");

    function createOn(root,name,attrs,text){
      var doc=root.ownerDocument, svg=root;
      while (svg.tagName!='svg') svg=svg.parentNode;
      var svgNS = svg.getAttribute('xmlns');
      var el = doc.createElementNS(svgNS,name);
      for (var attr in attrs){
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
          var parts = attr.split(':');
          if (parts[1]) el.setAttributeNS(
            svg.getAttribute('xmlns:'+parts[0]), parts[1], attrs[attr]
          );
          else el.setAttributeNS(null,attr,attrs[attr]);
        }
      }
      if (text) el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
      return root.appendChild(el);
    }          
  ]]></script> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Yes, that is great alternative! May I use your method in my project? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
set_label (10,50,'Qam&#218;raj')
```

with

```
set_lavel(10, 50, "Qam\u00DAraj");
```

"\u00DA" is four hex digits for Codepoint 218.

Similarly, your other label would be

```
set_label (10,50,'\u0398\u03b1\u03c1\u03c3\u03b1\u03bd\u03b4\u03b1\u03bb\u03b1')
```

If you want to find the hex for a Greek character, you can go to http://www.squarefree.com/shell/shell.html and type something like

```
var hex = "Α".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
[, "\\x0", "\\x", "\\u0", "\\u"][hex.length] + hex;
```

which for `"Α"` produces

```
\u0391
```

Comment: I found a possible solution on this site:
http://people.w3.org/rishida/tools/conversion/
this is a wonderful java script convertor from and to all variations of coding. Java Script engine behind this is just what I need for my problem. Just to see if i can use it in my project - i don't know, i must contact the author.