# How to put a symbol font character inside svg <text>?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am creating a chart with D3 and trying to add some icons from [Entypo font](http://www.entypo.com/characters/).
There is the character map with unicode codes for each symbol. Though when I do it like this:

```
.text(function (d) {
  return '&#128319;';
})
```

It just puts it as it is, not substituting it with a respective icon. When I put "U+1F53F" as an alternative, it doesn't put it either.
So, how to properly put the icon from that font inside SVG text element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830991/svg-text-element-with-unicode-characters) suggests that you can do it by putting in the actual Unicode character instead of the code. Just make sure that the charset of your page is set to UTF-8. You also need to make sure that the font is available, e.g. by [embedding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html).