# Using Font Awesome with jQuery SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

With a little help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg), I was able to show font awesome icons in static SVG.  But our app uses jQuery SVG, and it doesn't seem to be allowing SVG escape characters.  Here's a demo showing both running side by side:

http://jsfiddle.net/scruffles/m6Z7Y/4/

```
<text x="30" y="30">&#xf040</text>
```

Renders as a pencil, but

```
svg.text(g, 30, 30, '&#xf040');
```

renders as &#xf040

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG text element with Unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830991/svg-text-element-with-unicode-characters)

Comment: Just as a tip, you should not use jQuery SVG wiht jQuery versions 1.8 or higher. It has some conflicts with those versions. For example .width() and .height() return strings ("30px") instead of numbers. I ended up just using plain jQuery and to dynamically create elements use: $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "rect")); instead of $("<rect />")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5833265/901048), you should use `svg.text(g, 30, 30, '\uf040');` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/m6Z7Y/6/

Comment: how did you find this `\uf040'` ?

Comment: @TusharGupta It's nearly identical to the original `&#xf040`.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, instead of using the entity, you can either use raw Unicode in your JavaScript source ([copy/paste the character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f040/browsertest.htm)), or use a [Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences) in your plain ASCII JavaScript code:

```js
svg.text(g, 30, 60, '');       // A unicode f040 character
svg.text(g, 30, 30, '\uf040');
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m6Z7Y/7/

---

<sub>Also, note that XML entities begin with an ampersand and end with a semicolon—`&…;`—so you need a semicolon at the end for valid XML markup:</sub>

```xml
<text x="30" y="30">&#xf040;</text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I generated an object with the Font Awesome names and aliases as keys and unicode characters as values. That way you can make things more readable like this:

```
svg.text(g, 30, 60, FONT_AWESOME.pencil);
```

Here is the full list: https://github.com/the-grid/the-graph/blob/master/the-graph/font-awesome-unicode-map.js